# Is QueryDSL is good for Spring Boot Application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, querydsl, hibernate-criteria

as i know for Querying from Persistence we have below options
Criteria Query
QueryDsl e.t.c.

i am using queryDSL

so is that good approach? or any other library that i can use

Answer (score 3):

Criteria API is a bit tricky/complicated compared to Query DSL. So, I prefer Query DSL.

**Reasons:**

1. Type safety is the core principle of `Querydsl` and one of the best reasons to prefer it.
2. Compact implementation.
3. More like JPQL syntax.

Refer to the [Query DSL advantages](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.6.0/reference/html/ch01s02.html) doc for details.

Comment: Glad that you found it helpful! Cheers.

Comment: is it best approach to use it with DTO (using constructor) pattern? or need to follow another way ?

Comment: Yes! Absolutely.

Comment: Thanks Amit you helped me to clear my path,
currently i am stuck with N+1 problem in QueryDsl with DTO(constructor) pattern
have any idea how to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

QueryDSL is

- more similar to SQL so it might be easier to learn for people who have not touched Criteria before.
- more compact
- more type-safety
- closer to JPQL syntax